# Existing library for Version parsing (and increment operation)

Tags: java

I have a quiet simple task: Parse a version (e.g. "1.0.0") and increment the patch part by one ("1.0.1"). I know this is a quiet simple task, and while you're reading this I've probably finished my implementation. So I'm not asking how to implement that.

I love using existing and tested classes. So I'm still wondering if there is any existing class in the maven galaxy. I would already be happy with a version parser (i.e. without an increment operation). This sounds so much like a commons class, but searching google for any permutation of the words "java, version, class, library, -jdk" is not productive.

The version does follow the [Semantic Versioning scheme](http://semver.org/) (MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH) and is expected to contain only numbers. So it could be easily implemented by splitting, parsing to Integer and ++.

Comment: Hi Markus, interesting question. I'm not sure, but you could take a look at the Maven Release plugin. It automatically suggests a new version number, and I guess this is done based on parsing the old one. Maybe the source of the Maven Release plugin will guide you to the right solution?

Comment: I don't have idea about maven. but we do increment version through this code version:1.0.r${svn.Revision} using build.xml.

Comment: Erik: the to isn't intereseted in implementing it on his own but on an existing library, but you gave us a good keyword... Markus, what version do you want to increment, what will your program - using such a library - do? A bit context info is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is what you are looking for:

http://akutz.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/version-java/

Here is the source:

http://sourceforge.net/p/nvn/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/nvn-commons/src/main/java/net/sf/nvn/commons/Version.java

It is unit tested, you can parse and formate version strings and you can increment parts of the version string.

Comment: On a first sight it seems that it does not have an interface to increment a field. It has an setter/getter or incrementor (add) for fields, but the code is not aware of incrementing a field and resetting the minor fields (`1.2.8`; "`MINOR++`" --> `1.3.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is so embarrassing. I didn't even try to search for "version" in maven central. I did now and found in those few results: [com.cedarsoft.version.Version](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.cedarsoft.commons|version|6.0.1|bundle).